# Как отключить отображение приложения при обращении через cmd

Tags: c#, winforms, cmd, консоль

C# - Windows Form приложение

Обращение к приложению через команду /h (через ярлык или через cmd):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего в приложении должен выполниться код для команды /h (например запись значений в реестр), но при этом окно приложения не должно открываться, чтобы не мешать пользователю.

Нужен способ как это сделать, только по возможности подскажите как, т.к. не силен в C# (могу разобраться только в рабочих шаблонах).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Program.cs Вашего проекта есть команда:

```
    Application.Run(new Form1());
```

(вместо `Form1` - имя Вашей стартовой формы). Оберните это в проверку параметров

```
if (args.Contains("/h"))
{
    //ваша логика
}
else
{
    Application.Run(new Form1());
}
```

Ещё один момент. По умолчанию метод `Main` в WinForm-приложении выглядит как `static void Main()`, т.е. не предусматривает вызова с параметрами. Измените на         `static void Main(string[] args)`.

Comment: Я правильно Вас понял? <http://s29.postimg.org/mq1e8nvlj/cmd2.png>?

Comment: да, похоже на то. А что, что-то не работает?

Comment: Просто нужно несколько таких команд /h /d /f /g и т.д. куча "если", он же  "if"

Comment: Сам код отлично работает и то, что нужно, но теперь думаю как "if" заменить на case или foreach или, что-то подобное...

Comment: Про код в Вашем ответе Вы объяснили очень понятно, спасибо. Без важных моментов и подсказок не разобрался бы.

Comment: создайте отдельный класс-обработчик параметров, передавайте ему весь массив - и обрабатывайте внутри как нужно. Вряд ли это будет case - параметры же не взаимоисключающие. Не зная логики сказать сложно, ну и в целом это тема для отдельного вопроса :)